# Change ldap password from docker container by ldappasswd command

Tags: docker, ldap, change-password

I have script that user can change password to ldap. The user write his password and the script is sending the command to ldap server. I can`t do that other way, only this way ldap server creates propper passwords. The command is:

```
ldappasswd -x -D "uid=userwhocanchangepassword,cn=users,dc=example,dc=org" -w "userpass" -h ldap.host -S 'uid=usertochange,cn=users,dc=example,dc=org' -s 'passwordTochange'
```

userwhocanchangepassword - is user that has perrmissions to change other users passwords

Autside the container it works perfectly (password is changed) but when I try to run same command in the docker container insted of password change i get ldappasswd help:

```
Change password of an LDAP user
usage: ldappasswd [options] [user]
user: the authentication identity, commonly a DN
```

It`s strange but it works well if I delete the -s param with the password. But if I do that command is prompting to pass the password.

On my dev machine and inside the docker container is the same version of the ldappasswd. Docker is ubuntu container with installed ldap-utils.

Is any other way to modify this command, or maybe some one has simillar problem?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am guessing, but you may need to escape Double Quotes when passing a commend via docker exec. 
\"uid=userwhocanchangepassword,cn=users,dc=example,dc=org\"
Or try single quote.

Comment: Thx, but unfortunately that doesn't work either. Nothing changed if I escaped or change double quotes to single.

Comment: You're mixing double quotes `"` with single quotes `'`. Try changing the single quotes to double quotes: `-S "uid=usertochange,cn=users,dc=example,dc=org" -s "passwordTochange"`

Comment: Thx for help, but I tried double end single quotes and still the command is showing help instead of changing the password.